# How to give an empty HTML div CSS styling (background)?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a HTML div with an orange background. It has no elements inside of it and I would like the width to take up 100% of the page and the height to take up 50% of the page. How can I do this?
Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id=weldiv>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#weldiv{
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background:orange;
    text-align:center;
}
```

When this is run, a blank white page shows up

Comment: A height in percent only works if the parent element has an explicit height set as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a specific height to your `div` element, not `%` because this element is empty so you couldn't apply a `%` height value.

e.g

```css
#weldiv{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px; /*Example Value*/
    background: orange;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="weldiv"></div>
```